# Azure powershell - how to get FQDN from a VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am automating the deployment of several Azure VMs and I want to WinRM into each of them to finish the deployment. How do I find the FQDN of the VM from the script that creates it?

I'm looking for:

```
$psVirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $psVirtualMachine -Id $Nic.Id

$CreateNewVM = New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $GeoLocation -VM $psVirtualMachine

Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://<-- $CreateNewVM.FQDN -->:5986 -Credential $Cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck) -Authentication Negotiate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I find the FQDN of the VM from the script that creates it?

By default, Azure will not create FQDN for Azure VM, we can use powershell to set **public IP address** settings to set FQDN for Azure VM.

We can use this command to get FQDN:

```
$FQDN = (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name 'name of public IP' -ResourceGroupName jasonvm).DnsSettings.Fqdn
```

Like this:

```
PS C:\Users> (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name 'jasonvm-ip' -ResourceGroupName jasonvm).DnsSettings.Fqdn
jasontest321.japaneast.cloudapp.azure.com
```

To set FQDN for Azure VM, we can use this powershell

```
New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress  -Name -ResourceGroupName -Location -DomainNameLabel
```